# R - Manipulation of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, datatable, aggregate

I’ve the following data frame table

| S/N | Index 1 | Index 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 5 |
| B | 5 | 2 |
| C | 2 | 4 |

How do I change it to the following table?

| index | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Index 1 | 0% | 33.3% | 0% | 0% | 66.6% |
| Index 2 | 0% | 33.3% | 0% | 33.3% | 33.3% |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy syntax with `janitor`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

df1 %>% pivot_longer(-S_N) %>%
  tabyl(name, value) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2)

   name      2      4      5
 Index1 33.33%  0.00% 66.67%
 Index2 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%
```

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Please also consider [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) as usually desired on SO.  You can upvote as many answers as you feel helped you, per question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to see what fraction of counts are in each index for each value. It took me a few steps but does this roughly produce what you are looking for?

```
df1 <- data.frame("S_N" = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 "Index1" = c(5, 5, 2),
                 "Index2" = c(5, 2, 4))
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Index", values_to = "value", cols = c("Index1", "Index2"))

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Index) %>% 
  summarise(idx_cnt = n())

final_df <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Index, value) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "Index") %>% 
  mutate(frac = count / idx_cnt * 100) %>% 
  select(Index, value, frac) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = frac)
```

Result:

```
> final_df
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Index [2]
  Index    `2`   `5`   `4`
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Index1  33.3  66.7  NA  
2 Index2  33.3  33.3  33.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` function here is a way. Using data shared from @Carey Caginalp

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -S_N, names_to = 'index') %>%
  count(index, value) %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  complete(index, value = 1:max(value), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)

#  index    `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Index1     0  33.3     0   0    66.7
#2 Index2     0  33.3     0  33.3  33.3
```